# How to return ndarray in python3 ctypes?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, ctypes

I have a c++ function:

```
double* hiho() {
  double *res = new double[10];
  return res;
}
```

together with

```
from numpy.ctypeslib import ndpointer

mylib.hiho.restype = ndpointer(dtype=ctypes.c_double, shape=(10,))
```

When calling the function, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: '<P' is not a valid PEP 3118 buffer format string
```

I use Python 3.6.2

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce your error, but this works.  Provide a reproducible example if this doesn't help you fix it:

**test.cpp** (Windows)

```
#define API __declspec(dllexport) // Windows-specific export

extern "C" API double* hiho() {
  double *res = new double[10];
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
      res[i] = .1 * i;
  return res;
}
```

**test.py**

```
import ctypes
from numpy.ctypeslib import ndpointer

mylib = ctypes.CDLL('test')
mylib.hiho.restype = ndpointer(dtype=ctypes.c_double, shape=(10,))
print(mylib.hiho())
```

**Output**

```
[0.  0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated numpy to version 1.18.1.
Now, this works very well :

```
from numpy.ctypeslib import ndpointer

mylib.hiho.restype = ndpointer(dtype=ctypes.c_double, shape=(10,))
```

To update numpy simply :

```
pip install numpy --upgrade
```

For your info :

With numpy 1.15.4, I had the same error with your example Mark with *double or *int.

my compile lines on MacOS :

```
g++ -c -fPIC -std=c++17 test.cpp -o test.o

g++ -dynamiclib -undefined suppress -flat_namespace test.o -o test.dylib
```

or

```
g++ -c test.cpp -o test.o

g++ -dynamiclib -undefined suppress -flat_namespace test.o -o test.dylib
```

Error :

```
ValueError: '<P' is not a valid PEP 3118 buffer format string
```

Comment: yes, thanks, i know. it is because of my low reputation. I solved the problem with numpy update. I have updated my answer.